# SELECT IF (QUERY IN QUERY)

Tags: mysql, select, if-statement

I have  a simply query

```
SELECT AGENT FROM `SALES` WHERE PRICE='3000.00' AND COMDTE > '2014-02-02' AND COMDTE < '2014-03-02'
```

also I have second table where I have parametr RANK of the agent

**I need to select all sales where agent have RANK='1'**

but ther'e 2 tables. SALES and AGENTS and the param RANK in the AGENTS table

```
SELECT ID FROM `AGENTS` WHERE RANK = 1
```

my try is

```
SELECT AGENT FROM `SALES` WHERE PRICE='3000.00' AND COMDTE > '2014-02-02' AND COMDTE < '2014-03-02' IF ((SELECT ID FROM `AGENTS` WHERE RANK = 1 AND ID = AGENT),YES, NO) = YES
```

Comment: I don't know if we should give you +1 or -1 for inventing new syntax ...

Comment: learn to join two tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT AGENT 
FROM `SALES` 
WHERE PRICE='3000.00' 
AND COMDTE > '2014-02-02' 
AND COMDTE < '2014-03-02' 
AND AGENT IN (SELECT ID FROM `AGENTS` WHERE RANK = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a simple join

```
SELECT s.AGENT
FROM `SALES`  s
JOIN `AGENTS` a ON(s.AGENT =a.id)
WHERE s.PRICE='3000.00' 
AND s.COMDTE > '2014-02-02' 
AND s.COMDTE < '2014-03-02'
AND a.RANK = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

That won't Work, You have to create something called view table which is a new table that combine 2 tables and then retrieve data from it

learn about it here http://www.w3resource.com/sql/creating-views/creating-view.php